# Cómo trabajar con repositorios privados de git en VScode

Tags: git, github, vscode, configuración

Muy buenas a todos, veréis me estoy adentrando en esto de trabajar con el control de versiones en mis códigos. Estoy trabajando con VSCode y ya estoy trabajando sobre repositorios públicos de mi cuenta.

El problema me radica en el hecho de querer trabajar con mis repositorios privados, o sea encuentro y trabajo perfectamente con los públicos pero no me aparecen los privados.

¿Qué configuración tengo que hacer para poder ver esos repositorios privados en mi git desde VSCode?

Muchas gracias a todos de antemano

---

Pues abro la paleta de comando y busco `git: clone`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Selecciono crear desde desde github con el intro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y justo ahí me aparecen todos los repositorios de mi cuenta, pero claro, los públicos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por otro lado, intento poner directamente el enlace del repositorio privado en el buscador pero no aparece nada, de ahí mi pregunta

Comment: A que te referis con que no encontras los privados? donde no los encontras?

Comment: Como no me dejaba responder como yo considero que se debía, he incluido una respuesta más abajo para poder poner las fotos

Comment: No respondes a los comentarios en las respuestas. Edita la pregunta y añade la info para complementarla. Usa el enlace Editar que está bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas